# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglifyjs' with "gulp watch

Tags: gulp

I´m in my project folder on my terminal, and:

if I extecute:

```
     gulp -v
```

I get:

```
[15:47:15] CLI version 3.9.0
[15:47:15] Local version 3.9.0
```

if I excute:

```
 gulp watch
```

I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglifyjs'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
   at require (module.js:385:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>    (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/last/gulpfile.js:3:14)
   at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
   at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Then, I search in the gulpfile.js 3:14 and I see this:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
```

I was read about this, a lot people say "oh, do npm install", I do, and after make npm -v I get this:

```
 3.3.12
```

I was trying with a lot commands, but I dont know what happen. Maybe gulpfile.js?

Maybe I forgot a dependencie?

Comment: Just to clarify, when people say "do npm install" they're not talking about installing NPM. The letters stand for Node Package Manager, and it's used to install JavaScript packages and their dependencies.

Check out [NPM's site](https://www.npmjs.com/) for more information. Try searching for gulp-uglify, as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace
`require('gulp-uglifyjs');`
with
`require('gulp-uglify');`

see also https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify

Comment: `gulp-uglifyjs` is a legitimate package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifyjs

Comment: @iamchris, maybe, but I tried to resolve with "gulp-uglify" and I did it, now gulps works perfect. =)

Answer (score 10):

> Maybe I forgot a dependencie?

Yes maybe local installation will resolve you problem. Run next command in you project:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify
```